# Starting jar on different port than 8080 packed as exe

Tags: java, spring, jar, launch4j

In spring in the application.properties I have server.port = 8090 and it is working, but when I package the project in jar it is still running at 8080 is there a way to set the jar file port directlly from the project. I found a solution where I should write:

```
java -Dserver.port=8090 -jar myApplication.jar
```

But I am making executable wrapper with Launch4j and there is command lines args, but writing "-Dserver.port=8090" doesn't work there:

[image]

Any ideas how to change the port with launch4j?

Comment: Q: Does `-Dserver.port=8090` work with your particular Spring Boot .jar when you launch from the command line (instead of launch4j)?  Q: What about `--server.port=8090`?

Comment: @paulsm4 -Dserver.port=8090 works only from the console. I just tried --server.port=8090 and it works, thanks.